# How to call original method after it got prepend from outside

Tags: ruby, class, prepend

I'm refactoring some old code to fit to Ruby > 2. And there is some `alias_method_chain` which I want to remove.

But there is some part where the without method get called. Inside the method I have to `super` for sure but from outside?

Following is given:

```
module ExtraLog
  def log
    puts "ExtraLog"
    super
  end
end

class Klass
  prepend ExtraLog
  def log
    puts "Log"
  end
end

a = Klass.new
a.log 
#=> "ExtraLog"
#=> "Log"
```

How can i call the original log method now without that the prepended method get called? Something like `a.original_log`?

Comment: did you get it solved?

Comment: Yes, thank you very much! Can't do a upvote by now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Method#`super_method`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Method.html#method-i-super_method):

```
a.method(:log).super_method.call
#=> Log
```

Comment: Weird that you can't call #super directly within the method and have to use this. This solution worked for me as well.